# Why is spring Boot 2.4.5 with Junit5 and mocked beans is throwing StackOverflowErrors?

Tags: spring, mockito, integration-testing, junit5

## Context

1. Upgraded gradle from `5.5.1` to `7.0.2`
2. Tested - everything works
3. Upgraded spring from 2.1.5 to 2.4.1
4. Migrated test annotations from junit 4 to junit 5

### Result

1. Unittests work
2. Integration tests **DO NOT** work

## Issue

1. Starting integration tests fails when resetting Mocks in the application context
   `@ResetMocksTestExecutionListneer.resetMocks`
2. The problematic bean has the name `beanifyAuthenticationManager` and its proxying the `interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager`

   1. Detecting if this bean is a `mock` runs into an infinite loop.
   2. so does its `toString` method.

## Questions

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is this an issue that shall be reported to Spring?

## Additional information

1. Integration tests triggered by custom annotation defined as

```
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = {PmpTestApplication.class},
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {WithDomainAuthorizationExecutionListener.class},
  mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
  "spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false"})
public @interface AppIntTest {
```

2. Integration tests looks like

```
@AppIntTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SomeRestBusinessControllerIntTest extends AbstractControllerIntTest {
```

3. Actual `StackOverflowError` exception was thrown from

```
AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject
[...]
    try {
            if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(candidate) && candidate instanceof Advised) {
                Object target = ((Advised) candidate).getTargetSource().getTarget();
                if (target != null) {
                    return (T) getUltimateTargetObject(target);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to unwrap proxied object", ex);
        }
[...]
```

where it is easy to see how it can run in a StackOverflowError.
It'd need the check `target <> candidate` before calling the `getUltimateTargetObject` again recursively

Comment: In theory, the proposed `target <> candidate` check should be unnecessary, and I'd like to see why/how that occurs in your scenario. Thus, please open a ticket at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/new with a minimal project that reproduces the `StackOverflowError`, and we (the Spring Team) will investigate it.

Comment: Can you try externalizing the `AuthenticationManager` bean definition into a separate configuration class using a static method? This can often help with bean cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Though I don't have a clear explanation of why it happens, when I removed the explicit bean declaration from my security configuration, the issue stopped manifesting

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
[...]
    // this explicit bean declaration was removed
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager beanifyAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        // will use #configure to build the bean
        return authenticationManager();
    }
```

My guess is that this explicit bean declaration of the `AuthenticationManager` was needed for the past spring version to trigger certain security config mechanisms.

Comment: can you post also the exact error which is thrown?

Comment: @Boug : Added additional exception details + my 2 cents how I think it shall be fixed

Comment: you may need to post a minimum replicated example project in Github and open a ticket in spring. What you describe is that the exception is thrown from spring it self. That definitely belongs to spring to solve.  Not registering `AuthenticationManager` as a bean is not a viable solution. It may be just the cause they need to check

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the Spring Framework, the corresponding ticket can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215