# I get stackOverflowError in spring security test

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-security, spring-test

Security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConf {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

I have a simple application, if I try to start the main it works, however when I start my test class I get this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.base/java.lang.StackTraceElement.of(StackTraceElement.java:526)
            at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:828)
            at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(Throwable.java:820)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:79)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    and it always continues the same way ...
```

in debug I tried to recover the error but I only see this `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object.`

The test only works if I remove the `authenticationManagerBean`but i need `authenticationManagerBean` to inject `AutthenticationManager` in my app.

I know that I could use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and then add the bean going to override the metood of this class. But as `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, I would not want to use it.

this problem arose from the fact that I have switched from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to SecurityFilterChain and am getting this error as I changed the config class

I created this simple project which replicate the error of my main project. If you try to start the application it works, but the test doesn't. https://github.com/lako12/demo

The project is very simple, there are only 3 classes plus a test class.

Comment: I am in a situation like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546793/why-is-spring-boot-2-4-5-with-junit5-and-mocked-beans-is-throwing-stackoverflowe

Comment: yes, I used that guide to make the switch to SecurityFilterChain

Comment: In this guide is no `authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();` line. It looks like you have to expose your custom `AuthenticationManager` not the one from the configuration. Where do you need to access it?

Comment: You should not need an `AuthenticationManager` at all, at least not the one from `AuthenticationConfiguration`. I'll assume that you have an `UserDetailsService` bean, therefore you can create a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` using that `UserDetailsService` and exposing an `new ProviderManager(myDaoAuthenticationProvider)` as a bean to use in your application

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I have the same issue in my spring boot microservice example. As I still couldn't fix the issue, it is possible to help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja

Comment: @dur I have a similar issue but I couldn't fix it. Can you help me if you solve the issue? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-spring-security-servicetest-and-controllertest-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue on spring github and it was reported as a bug that will be fixed by spring framework version 5.3.24.
This is the link of the discussion.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215

Comment: I have the same issue in my spring boot microservice example. As I still couldn't fix the issue, it is possible to help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the `AuthenticationManager` in your application? From what I understand, you want to configure a `SecurityFilterChain` so you could just create this Bean instead:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConf {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated(); //or whatever else you need
      return http.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but I couldn't fix it. Can you help me if you solve the issue? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-spring-security-servicetest-and-controllertest-for