# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when trying to create a Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to create a REST API. I can create an account and login, but when I try to get the users the following error occurs: `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`.

I know that the problem involves recursion method callings, but I just can't see where it is.

## **User model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_USER")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
   private Long userId;
   @Column(name = "COMPLETE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 60)
   private String name;
   @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
   private String username;
   @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 200)
   private String password;

   // token e tokenCreationDate são usados para fins de recuperação de senha
   @Column(name = "TOKEN")
   private String token;
   @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE_TOKEN")
   private LocalDateTime tokenCreationDate;

   public User() {
   }

   public User(Long userId, String name, String username, String password) {
      this.userId = userId;
      this.name = name;
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
   }

   public Long getUserId() {
      return userId;
   }

   public void setUserId(Long userId) {
      this.userId = userId;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public String getUsername() {
      return username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
   }

   @Override
   public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
      return Collections.emptyList();
   }

   @Override
   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }

   public String getToken() {
      return token;
   }

   public void setToken(String token) {
      this.token = token;
   }

   public LocalDateTime getTokenCreationDate() {
      return tokenCreationDate;
   }

   public void setTokenCreationDate(LocalDateTime tokenCreationDate) {
      this.tokenCreationDate = tokenCreationDate;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      User user = (User) o;
      return userId.equals(user.userId);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(userId);
   }
}
```

## **User repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   boolean existsByUsername(String username);

   Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

   User findByToken(String token);
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

   private final UserRepository userRepository;

   private final PasswordEncoder encoder;

   public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
      this.userRepository = userRepository;
      this.encoder = encoder;
   }

   public List<User> findAll() {
      return userRepository.findAll();
   }
   
   public boolean  existsByUsername(String username) {
      return userRepository.existsByUsername(username);
   }
   
   public HttpStatus register(User user) {

      // invalid password
      if(!Utilities.validatePassword(user.getPassword())) {
         return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
      }

      // Address already in use
      if(existsByUsername(user.getUsername())) {
         return HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
      }

      // Successful
      String password = encoder.encode(user.getPassword());
      user.setPassword(password);
      userRepository.save(user);

      return HttpStatus.CREATED;
   }
}
```

## **User controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class UserController {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @GetMapping("/all")
   public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll() {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findAll());
   }
}
```

Signup controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/signup")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class SignUpController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
        HttpStatus status =  userService.register(user);

        if(status.equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                    .body("The password must include uppercase and lowercase letters numbers and symbols");
        }

        if(status.equals(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Address already in use");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Successful");
    }
}
```

## **Login controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class LoginController {

   @Autowired
   private LoginService loginService;

   @PostMapping
   public ResponseEntity<UserLogin> authentication(@RequestBody UserLogin user) {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(loginService.login(user));
   }
}
```

## **Login service**

```
@Service
public class LoginService {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @Autowired
   private PasswordEncoder encoder;

   public UserLogin login(@NotNull UserLogin user) {
      Optional<User> u = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

      if(u.isEmpty() || !encoder.matches(user.getPassword(), u.get().getPassword())) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Invalid credentials");
      }

      String auth = user.getUsername() + ":" + user.getPassword();
      byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
      String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

      user.setToken(authHeader);

      return user;
   }
}
```

## **Security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
      return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
   }
   
   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/signup").permitAll()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/password/**").permitAll()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .httpBasic();
      return http.build();
   }
}
```

And finally... the stack trace

```
ava.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport$MethodCacheKey.equals(AdvisedSupport.java:580) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:940) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:468) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:199) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
```

it repeats forever...

Following some tutorials I tried to change dependencies, put some endpoints into the same class and refactor the entire project.

Comment: try to remove the bean authenticationManager in SecurityConfig class. I had the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883122/i-get-stackoverflowerror-in-spring-security-test/73933077#73933077

Comment: It worked! So simple, but so confusing as well. Thank so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the bean authenticationManager in SecurityConfig class. I had the same problem.
Ready here
[I get stackOverflowError in spring security test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883122/i-get-stackoverflowerror-in-spring-security-test/73933077#73933077)